# converting int to List<double?>, ChartJS Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, chart.js

I'm working on a web application. I found this interesting https://github.com/mattosaurus/ChartJSCore. to use charts in my application.

The charts are working successfully in most pages. But in one page i have the following idea:

I have 3 properties (Appropriate, Inappropriate, NoInteraction) in my model all with type (int) and i need to keep it as integer to manipulate other functionalities in the application. Each property will be represented as one series in the chart and it should be list or array of 15 integer always.

Here is my properties in Session Model:

```
    public int DayNumber { get; set; } 
    public int Appropriate { get; set; }
    public int NotAppropriate { get; set; } 
    public int NoInteraction { get; set; }
```

Here is my Controller:

```
     public IActionResult Details()
        {

            var result = _db.Session.ToList();

//I want this appropriateLine to be passed to GenerateLineChart method but whenever i tried i came up with an error of converting types.
            var AppropriateLine = result.Select(x => x.Appropriate).ToList(); 

            Chart lineChart = GenerateLineChart();
            ViewData["LineChart"] = lineChart;

            return View();
        }

    private static Chart GenerateLineChart()
    {
      
        Chart chart = new Chart();
        chart.Type = Enums.ChartType.Line;

        ChartJSCore.Models.Data data = new ChartJSCore.Models.Data();
        

        data.Labels = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15" };

        LineDataset AppropriateDataset = new LineDataset()
        {
            Label = "Appropriate Data Line",
            Data = new List<double?>() { 2, 6, 2, 6, 2, 6 }, //Here i want this to be filled with data from AppropriateLine variable, it works for the fixed value only
            Fill = "false",
            LineTension = 0.1,
            BackgroundColor = ChartColor.FromHexString("#FF6384"),
            BorderColor = ChartColor.FromHexString("#FF6384"),
            BorderCapStyle = "butt",
            BorderDash = new List<int> { },
            BorderDashOffset = 0.0,
            BorderJoinStyle = "miter",
            PointBorderColor = new List<ChartColor>() { ChartColor.FromHexString("#FF6384"), },
            PointBackgroundColor = new List<ChartColor>() { ChartColor.FromHexString("#fff") },
            PointBorderWidth = new List<int> { 1 },
            PointHoverRadius = new List<int> { 5 },
            PointHoverBackgroundColor = new List<ChartColor>() { ChartColor.FromHexString("#FF6384"), },
            PointHoverBorderColor = new List<ChartColor>() { ChartColor.FromHexString("#FF6384"), },
            PointHoverBorderWidth = new List<int> { 2 },
            PointRadius = new List<int> { 1 },
            PointHitRadius = new List<int> { 10 },
            SpanGaps = false
        };

      
        data.Datasets = new List<Dataset>();
        data.Datasets.Add(AppropriateDataset);
      

        Options options = new Options()
        {
            Scales = new Scales()
        };

        Scales scales = new Scales()
        {
            YAxes = new List<Scale>()
            {
                new CartesianScale()
            }
        };

        CartesianScale yAxes = new CartesianScale()
        {
            Ticks = new Tick()
        };

        Tick tick = new Tick()
        {
            Callback = "function(value, index, values) {return '' + value;}"
        };

        yAxes.Ticks = tick;
        scales.YAxes = new List<Scale>() { yAxes };
        options.Scales = scales;
        chart.Options = options;

        chart.Data = data;

        return chart;
    }
```

How can i implement this "Explicit Casting" of appropriateLine variable which is (int) before passing it to GenerateLineChart().

Note that i don't want to change Model properties type since many functions depend on it. Also, I cannot change Data type from List<double?> since many other problems solved by adding this.

I tried many casting solutions but none of them works for me such as:

1. (List<double?>)result.Select(x => x.Appropriate);
2. private static Chart GenerateLineChart((List<double?>)AppropriateLine)
3. I've read about "Convert all" method but not worked.

Any help is much appreciated,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to still return List<double> but all the values are rounded (or truncated) to an integer?   `result.Select(x => (double)(int)x.Appropriate).ToList()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you mention, it seems that the data passed to `GenerateLineChart` will only be used for UI purposes. That is, this method can get an appropriate *copy* of the original data. If this is the case, then, the solution you attempted with

```cs
(List<double?>)result.Select(x => x.Appropriate)
```

was very close, but the cast needs to be done inside `Select`, i.e.

```cs
result.Select(x => (double?)x.Appropriate)
```

Here is a sketch of your code with that change

```cs
public IActionResult Details()
{
    var result = _db.Session.ToList();
    var AppropriateLine = result.Select(x => (double?)x.Appropriate).ToList(); 
    var lineChart = GenerateLineChart(AppropriateLine);
    // Rest or your code
}

private static Chart GenerateLineChart(IEnumerable<double?> data)
{
    // Your code as is here ....

    LineDataset AppropriateDataset = new LineDataset()
    {
        Data = data,
        // Rest of your code
    }
    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can check at the moment that you need the list if the number is double or int `bool isInt = d == (int)d;` and parse to use it only for that time on an aux.